# Native leak in BitmapFactory.cpp?

Tags: android, frameworks, java-native-interface, native, memory-leaks

platform/frameworks/base/core/jni/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.cpp:212
...

```
 if (peeker.fPatchIsValid) {
     size_t ninePatchArraySize = peeker.fPatch->serializedSize();
     ninePatchChunk = env->NewByteArray(ninePatchArraySize);        **<= alloc here**
     if (NULL == ninePatchChunk) {
         return nullObjectReturn("ninePatchChunk == null");
     }
     jbyte* array = (jbyte*)env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(ninePatchChunk,
                                                           NULL);
     if (NULL == array) {
                                    **<= should we release ninePatchChunk here**
         return nullObjectReturn("primitive array == null");
     }
     peeker.fPatch->serialize(array);
     env->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(ninePatchChunk, array, 0);
 }
```

GC will realese this objects or we should do this ?

Comment: you should, since native heap is different from the java heap

Comment: So aosp has a native leaks and they should fix it ?

Comment: no they not. You should call recycle on the bitmpa's object. recycle will free the native heap

Comment: but if we have an error(array == NULL), we don't have a bitmap, so ?

Comment: it is a simple function: jobject android::nullObjectReturn(const char msg[]) {
    if (msg) {
        SkDebugf("--- %s\n", msg);
      }
      return NULL;

Comment: GetPrimitiveArrayCritical returns null if an exeception is thrown and the exeception throwen is OOM. ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical will release the "array  memroy". All looks good to me. Maybe somebody more skilled

Comment: yes you're right, but what with ninePatchChunk object ? we allocate memory here ninePatchChunk = env->NewByteArray(ninePatchArraySize); and we don't release this mem if array == NULL

Answer (score 0):

So if error occur, this is a leak or not ?